# Utilização de loop no codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá, Tudo bem com vocês?

Estou tendo um grande problema no codeigniter que não estou sabendo resolver,

eu tenho um helper onde ele funciona da seguinte forma

```
function forms($a){
        for(i=0;i<=$a;i++){
             <input type='text' name='forms_$i'>
         }
 }
```

onde anteriormente usei um codigo para gerar a quantidade de inputs que eu queria, entretanto não muito bem como receber esses valores no meu controller, pois preciso pegar os valores recebidos nesses formulários e colocar eles no banco de dados.

Se alguém puder me ajudar nessa parte eu agradeceria muito, tanto em uma maneira de receber os valores ou uma maneira mais pratica.

Obrigado a todos.

P.S: As outras partes estão corretas no meu codigo, so não sei exatamente como receber os valores no meus controllers para colocar eles no banco de dados.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para receber os dados do post no controller utilize:

```
$valor = $this->input->post("input_name");
```

Para salvar no banco de dados utilize:

```
$this->db->insert("nome_tabela", $dados); //$dados deve ser um array
```

A questão é como seria a estrutura do seu banco dados. Mas o model seria simples:

```
class FormularioModel extends CI_Model {

   public function inserir($dados) {
       $this->db->insert("nome_tabela", $dados); // lembrar de carregar biblioteca database
   }
}
```

Agora se sua tabela tivesse dois campos: *nome_campo*, *valor_campo* seu método no controller seria:

```
public function salvarDados() {
   $this->load->model("FormularioModel", "model");
   for($i = 0; $i < $a; $i++) {
      $dados = [
         "nome_campo" => "forms_$i",
         "valor_campo" => $this->input->post("forms_$i")
      ];
      $this->model->inserir($dados);
   }
}
```

Agora uma alternativa menos viável: se você tiver uma tabela com várias colunas como: forms_1, forms_2, forms_3......

```
public function salvarDados() {
       $this->load->model("FormularioModel", "model");
       $dados = array();
       for($i = 0; $i < $a; $i++) {
          $dados["forms_$i"] = $this->input->post("forms_$i");
       }
       $this->model->inserir($dados);
   }
```

Comment: deu certo no começo, entretanto quando eu aumento a quantidade de dados do [$dados] ele da o seguinte erro

'Error Number: 1048

Column 'bin1' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `binaria` (`questao`, `bin1`, `bin2`) VALUES ('2s121s12', NULL, NULL)

Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/SAO/system/database/DB_driver.php

Line Number: 691'

Comment: consegui resolver, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 2):

Defina o nome dos campos como um array

```
function forms($a){
    $r = '';
    for(i=0;i<=$a;i++){
        $r .= '<input type="text" name="nome_do_campo['.$i.']">';
    }
    return r;
}

echo forms(5);
```

Para receber os dados basta iterar o array

```
if (is_array($this->input->post('nome_do_campo')) {
   foreach ($this->input->post('nome_do_campo') as $value) {
       echo $value.PHP_EOL.'<br>';
   };
};
```